# Iterating with a for loop in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out what this is actually called and where I can find the answer for it. I can't understand the difference in

```
for (Treet treet : treets) { }
```

I don't know what the different "treet" mean. can someone help me or at least tell me what it's called?

Comment: Bad question title. It's a down-vote and close question vote magnet, so please change it soon.

Comment: _Enhanced for statement_

Comment: @Andy Turner, thank you for the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (Treet treet : treets) { }
```

This is an *enhanced for statement* (although often referred to as an *enhanced for loop*). You are saying that you want to do something for every element in some collection of things. (Well, actually, you're doing nothing here, but never mind).

In English: "For every `Treet` in `treets`, do something".

`Treet` is a type. Somewhere you need a class called `Treet` defined. If it's in a different package, you need to import it.

`treets` is either an `Iterable<? extends Treet>`, meaning you could call `treets.iterator()` and use the result in the standard `hasNext()`/`next()` way; or an array of something which extends `Treet`. It's something you can iterate through.

`treet` is a single element from the iterable/array. You can use it only inside the body of the loop.

Comment: So how would it be read if I were saying it out loud in English?

Comment: @Downvoter: care to explain? I can understand why somebody new to Java might find it confusing.

Comment: Thank you Andy Turner. I wasn't trying to be a bother, I just know that StackOverfow usually has a community of people that understand and are helpful to those of us that have a little less knowledge than others. Thank you for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

Thats a `forach` loop, it iterates through the array/list/... and performs the actions defined in the loop to every element in the list which is referenced by treet.